# Basics in running a module in python

Tags: python, encoding, module, importerror

I'm a total newbie to Python and I'm having trouble running a simple module in IDLE.

1. Is there anything to look out for if you create a module in a text editor?
2. If it is saved on my desktop, I'll need to add this to the PYTHONPATH. I did this but I still get an error when I try to import the module (named sample):

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
       import sample
     File "/Users/Me/Desktop/sample.py", line 1
   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xb6' in file /Users/Me/Desktop/sample.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details (sample.py, line 1)
   ```

Seems like the error is something to do with non-ASCII character. How do I declare encoding? Anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What text editor are you using? (and please show your code, at least what's on line 2).

Comment: Did you read the linked PEP?

Comment: Do you have a non-ascii charecter like ÅÄÖ in your code? or maybe as a comment in your code?

Comment: Try using `# coding=utf-16`

Comment: Nope, I don't seem to have a non-ASCII in my code, no comment either.

Answer (score 0):

In sample.py you have to declare the encoding.

Use this on line 1 of sample.py and you'll be fine:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: I'm using LibreOffice. Does the font I'm using matter? I tried adding the # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on line 1 but still doesnt' work. 
I'm trying this to get a hang of modules, so I typed a simple code:
a=1
b=2
print a+b

Comment: @kastp Font *may* matter. Try using `utf-16`